# Scala integration test not picking config properties

Tags: scala

I have an Scala project with integration test with following folder structure

```
My Project
  - app
  - it
    - com.anjib.my.pkg
    - resources
      - application.regression.devl.conf
```

I want to overwrite one of the properties by putting in `application.regression.devl.conf` file but while running integration test its still pulling top level property.

For example some where in project there is

```
someKey=someValue
```

I put

```
somekey=otherValue
```

in  `application.regression.devl.conf`. But integration tests are still picking `someValue`

My build.sbt looks like

```
lazy val `my-project` = (project in file("."))
  ....
  .configs( IntegrationTest )
  .settings( Defaults.itSettings : _*)
  ....
```

)

Config loading as

```
def apply(): Config = {
  val environment = determineEnvironment
  val defaultConfig = ConfigFactory.load()
  val envConfig: Config = ConfigFactory.load(s"application.$environment.conf")
  val regressionSuiteConfig = ConfigFactory.load(s"application.regression.$environment.conf")
  regressionSuiteConfig.withFallback(envConfig).withFallback(defaultConfig)
```

}

Update: ID I do `Ctrl + Shift + F10` in IntelliJ it did pick up `otherValue`. So it has issue only with `sbt it:test`

Comment: How are you loading config? By default it looks for `application.conf` and `reference.conf`, not `application.regression.devl.conf`.

Comment: Updated question with config loading code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the `javaOptions` in sbt like this:

```
javaOptions in IntegrationTest += "-Dconfig.resource=" + System.getProperty("config.resource", "application.regression.devl.conf")
```

With this sbt will set the `config.resource` parameter to "application.regression.devl.conf" if nothing is passed explicitly.

Comment: How I can parameteriz the end part in sbt.build? "application.regression.$env.conf